# Creation of visitor profiles using microposts input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a app of which a unique user registers people entering a building.

The user takes the person's name, ID, plus a picture. When a person is registered,it updates a feed (like twitter's feed) that shows who entered the place (showing only the name and id). Each addition to the feed is actually a data model called "micropost". So each user has many microposts, and "micropost" belongs to "user".

The feed has to show all people who entered the building at a given day, both newly registered visitors and visitors registered long ago who just happened to pass by.

The issue is: i need that when the user clicks on visitor's name in the feed, it gets redirected to a profile page of that particular visitor, showing his/her complete info (name,ID and photo), plus the dates of all prior visits. I need to have many microposts redirecting to the same visitor profile, if they are showing information about the same person.

I'm trying to figure out the model relation between the user, microposts and visitors profiles. I don't know how it would work in this case.

The relation between user and micropost is easy to get, because users are unique. The problem is that microposts aren't, and as just said, even already registered visitors must be shown in the feed.

Thanks for any constructive feedback.

Comment: By the way? What's the issue you are facing. Please mention ?

Comment: Are you asking for, how to list the microposts of other user when you move to his/her profile page ?

Comment: Hey Ajay. I don't know how the model relation between users, microposts and profiles would work in this case. Plus i don't know how to show the particular visitor's visit history in his/her profile.

Comment: You will have only 2 models here user & micropost(sharing has-many relationship). 
and to show the information in the profile page, you need to access the users/show action. that's all .

Comment: Most important, you should try to create a basic structure of code first. give some try on creating user, micropost association. Further you can work on the profile page information.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are facing issue with microposts,visitors history

```
create table visitors(user_id,post_id, created_at)
```

1) When user visit post, insert a new record in the visitors table with the id of post, fetch record from visitor table to display previous user history.

Answer (score 0):

**in your models:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :microposts
end
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**in controller:**

```
@user = User.find(:id)
```

**in view:**

```
<p>@user.name</p>
@user.microspots.order(:created_at).each do |mp|
  <p>IN:<%=mp.created_at%></p>
end
```

I hope this help you.